# How to check if the a query returns something or does not in django?

Tags: django

I am having this :`items=order.orderitem_set.all()` in  my views.py that gives the items in a order. Currently this is under my cart view. The problem I am facing is that even if a persons cart is empty that is there are no items still the user can go to billing page. So is there any way in my views.py so that I can check whether there are item in items and return alert if not.

Comment: do you need to fetch the items if they're there or do you only need to know the count

Comment: I am doing `for item in items` to fetch if i need to alter something. but for this I only need to see if there is a item or not

Comment: sounds like you just need to execute the query then as you'll be executing it later on anyway

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to evaluate the query, I believe you need to fetch the items either way here, so best seems to just use `len`

```
if len(items):
    # has items
else:
    # empty
```

if you just need the count though, you can use `.count`, which will be a more efficient query if you ONLY need the count and will not be fetching the items themselves later...

```
if items.count():
    # has items
else:
    # empty
```

Comment: It would be better if  I can just use if for checking the count. so what would be the opposite of if items.count() so that it can be smthing like this: `if no items: #empty`

Comment: it's not better because you're executing redundant queries if you need to fetch the items anyway later, but the opposite of `if items.count()` is `if not items.count()`

Answer (score 0):

If I am clear about your situation probably you need to do the following:

```
if items.exists():
    # send the user to billing
else:
    # send some message to the template and show the message to the user
```